# python eveapi convert the expiration date

Tags: python

i am working with eveapi for the game Eve Online
https://github.com/ntt/eveapi
http://wiki.eve-id.net/APIv2_Account_APIKeyInfo_XML

Now i can get the expire date of an API by running the following:

```
import eveapi
api = eveapi.EVEAPIConnection()
auth = api.auth(keyID=4055832, vCode="W7LF0Q8mqgYGpAbLiZgeO6bCpQq1PZ4rbgvlt8nyM4Iy1giko38rAJtEE8WuJ5wT")
expires = auth.account.APIKeyInfo().key.expires
```

But this returns the following number 1453327533
How do i convert this to a real date?

Answer (score 0):

The number is a fromtimestamp  (amount of seconds since UNIX epoch, 1 jan 1970)
So to get the datetime you simply do:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.fromtimestamp(int(expires))
```